# Update com Ajax + Pdo

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

Eu realizei o UPDATE com AJAX + PDo, porém, está afetando apenas uma linha, as demais não são afetadas. Já tentei varias coisas, mas não estou conseguindo resolver, se alguém poder me ajudar.

```js
    
       
function uptade_cat() {
    
    var valor_update=$("#valor_update").val();
    var id_cat_update=$("#id_cat_update").val();
    var nome_categoria_update=$("#nome_categoria_update").val();
 

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "caixa/categoria_uptade.php",
            data: {nome_categoria:nome_categoria_update, valor:valor_update, id_cat:id_cat_update},
            dataType: "JSON",
            success: function (data) {
    $('#valor_update').val(data.valor_uptade);
    $('#nome_categoria_update').val(data.nome_categoria);
    $('#id_cat_update').val(data.id_cat_update);
    $('#alert_message3').html('<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert"><strong>Sucesso!</strong> Categoria Atualizado.<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>');
   $('#categoria_uptade_form').reload(); 

    
            },
            error: function() {
    $('#erro').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert"><strong>Erro!</strong> Ocorreu algum problema ao atualizar categoria.<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div>');
       
           
            },
        });
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-12">

  <div class="card-header">
                                <strong class="card-title">Editar Categoria</strong>
                            </div>
   <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table">
              <table class="table table-striped" style="width:100%">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="td-actions">Registro</th>
                    <th class="td-actions">Categoria</th>
                    <th class="td-actions">Valor</th>
                    <th class="td-actions">Editar</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
<?PHP
$select = "SELECT * from caixa_categoria ORDER BY id_cat DESC ";

  
  try{
   $result = $conexao->prepare($select);   
   $result->execute();
   $contar = $result->rowCount();
   if($contar>0){
    while($mostra = $result->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
?>           
                  <tr>
     <td> <?php echo $mostra->nome_categoria;?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $mostra->categoria;?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $mostra->valor;?> </td>
                    <td class="td-actions text-center"> <a href="" class="btn btn-outline-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cotegoria_<?php echo $mostra->id_cat;?>"><i class="far fa-edit"></i> Editar</td>
    </tr>
     
<?php
}  
   
   }else{
    echo '<div class"alert alert-danger">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
                      <strong>Aviso!</strong> Não há post cadastrado em nosso banco de dados.
                </div>';
   }
   
  }catch(PDOException $e){
   echo $e;
  }
     
  ?>   
                
                  
                
                </tbody>
              </table>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>


<!-- Modal -->
<?php 

   $result = $conexao->prepare('SELECT * from caixa_categoria');  
   $result->execute();
    while($mostra = $result->FETCH(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)):
  
?>
<div class="modal fade" id="cotegoria_<?php echo $mostra['id_cat'] ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Categoria: <?php echo $mostra['nome_categoria'] ?> (<?php echo $mostra['categoria'] ?>)</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="categoria_uptade_form" name="categoria_uptade_form">
     <div class="form-row">
      <input type="hidden" name="id_cat_update" id="id_cat_update" value="<?php echo $mostra['id_cat'] ?>" > 
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Nome Categoria</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome_categoria_update" id="nome_categoria_update" value="<?php echo $mostra['nome_categoria'] ?>">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="inputEmail4">Valor</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="valor_update" id="valor_update" value="<?php echo $mostra['valor'] ?>">
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
   
        <div id="alert_message3"></div>
        <div id="erro"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="uptade_cat()">Atualizar</button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

categoria_uptade

```
 <?php 
    include ('../../conexao/conecta.php');

    $id_cat= $_POST['id_cat'];
    $nome_categoria= $_POST['nome_categoria'];
    $valor= $_POST['valor'];

    $stmt = $conexao->prepare("UPDATE caixa_categoria SET nome_categoria=:nome_categoria, valor=:valor WHERE id_cat=:id_cat");

    $stmt->bindparam(':id_cat', $id_cat);
    $stmt->bindparam(':nome_categoria', $nome_categoria);
    $stmt->bindparam(':valor', $valor);


    if($stmt->execute())
    {
      $res="Data Inserted Successfully:";
      echo json_encode($res);
    }
    else {
      $error="Not Inserted,Some Probelm occur.";
      echo json_encode($error);
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: qual a duvida? explica melhor

Comment: isso deve ser porque deve ter alguma virgula que nao esta fechada ou esta no lugar errado  olha cada campo e verifica para achar o erro mais rapido usa a aba network do navegador e veja se todos os dados estão sendo passados

Comment: @WeesSmith  no update apenas um ID eu consigo atualizar, os restantes não consigo.

Comment: @diogoDsa vou fazer isso ! Obrigado

Comment: vc quer atualizar vários ids de uma vez?

Comment: @WeesSmith não quero atualizar apenas um!